# How do I know if I have successfully connected to the URL I opened a connection with?

Tags: java, url, jakarta-ee, networking, connection

To check if I can connect to the web-app named *service* I open a connection to its address.How do I check if have connected to this *URL/Service* ? I was thinking of sending some sort of status method (as a client tries to open connection to this URL) that determines if the client was able to establish a successful connection to the *service*. But how do I do that ?

I was trying something like this :

```
          final URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8084/service/index.jsp");
          final URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
          InputStream response = urlc.getInputStream();
          // Now call a method in the service app that sends a status method...
          // .....or can I get away with this ?
```

Comment: How about using url.getResponseCode() == OK (200) to check if the web-app returned an OK status?

Comment: @Waqas what method is it ? I am sure it isn't a predefined method..?

Comment: it's in HttpUrlConnection class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest

```
    URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775103/how-do-i-know-if-i-have-successfully-connected-to-the-url-i-opened-a-connection");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
```

it prints `200` (OK)

Comment: The problem with this is that if there is a connection timeout, it will throw SocketTimeoutException exception